# Keyword - Inline - Is really forcing compiler to replace it multiple places?

Tags: c++, inline

I have the below code :

```
static inline void print(const std::string& value)
{
    std::cout<< value <<std::endl;
}
```

Is the above function really forcing compiler to replace it multiple places?
I want to know whether is it really helpful?

> Since this meaning of the keyword inline is non-binding, compilers are
>   free to use inline substitution for any function that's not marked
>   inline, and are free to generate function calls to any function marked
>   inline. Those optimization choices do not change the rules regarding
>   multiple definitions and shared statics listed above.

[Inline reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline)

Comment: No, and yes. In any case, that's not really something to worry about.

Comment: @Quentin while writing code many people use it but if not required and handled by compiler then why developer should warry about it?

Comment: As far as i know, it is just a suggestion for the compiler to prefer inlining the function rather than function call, so it is up to compiler, it maybe inlines or not. But the important part is, as cppreference.com says that, it permits the functions defined multiple times in different translation units but compiler expects all the definitions are same (otherwise causes undefined behaviour)

Answer (score 2):

The compiler's optimizer is complex and will use heuristics to decide whether to inline code. There are many factors involved in that decision, and use of `inline` is probably considered. There exist things like MSVC's [`__forceinline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/inline-functions-cpp?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019) which may give a bigger nudge to that decision but will still not guarantee it.

But in general you can trust the compiler to make the right decision, and functionally there will be no difference to you. You can use recursion, take the address of that function, and the compiler will make it work, inline or not.

The biggest practical difference is what @arnes said:

> it permits the functions defined multiple times in different translation units but compiler expects all the definitions are same (otherwise causes undefined behaviour)

Comment: MSVC gives me linker errors if I declare something `inline` and put the definition in a cpp file instead of a header. That's one consistent practical effect.

Comment: I think your observation is wrong. .h, .cpp, doesn't matter to your compiler. But this is off-topic to OP's question.

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood you. Indeed for `inline` functions, the body of the function needs to be visible to the translation unit.